# Jest SpyOn not working for service in NgRx component store effect

Tags: angular, jestjs, ngrx

```
  readonly loadReviewByRouteId = this.effect(
    (): Observable<EmployeeReview> =>
      this.route.params.pipe(
        switchMap(({id}) => this.reviewService.getReviewById(id)),
        tap((review) => this.setEmployeeReview(review))
      )
  )
```

test setup:

```
const mockReviewService = {
   getReviewById() {
      console.log('here!')
   }

    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [RouterTestingModule.withRoutes([{path: '**', redirectTo: ''}])],
      providers: [
        ReviewDetailsStore,
        {
          provide: ReviewService,
          useValue: mockReviewService
        },
        {
          provide: ActivatedRoute,
          useValue: {
            params: of({id: 123})
          }
        }
      ]
    })
```

and the actual test:

```
    it('should call the review service with the route param id', () => {
      const getReviewServiceSpy = jest.spyOn(reviewService, 'getReviewById')
      reviewDetailsStore.loadReviewByRouteId()
      expect(getReviewServiceSpy).toHaveBeenCalled()
    })
```

I am trying to assert that the function getReviewById is called. When I run the test, the console.log is outputted by I am getting an assertion error that the function is NOT called.

```
    expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalledWith(...expected)

    Expected: called with 0 arguments

    Number of calls: 0
```

Comment: Wrap your test in `waitForAsync`

Comment: doesnt fix the issue

Comment: See full answer below

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure that `loadReviewByRouteId` has finished executing before the `expect`:

```
it('should call the review service with the route param id', waitForAsync(() => {
    const getReviewServiceSpy = jest.spyOn(reviewService, 'getReviewById')
    reviewDetailsStore.loadReviewByRouteId().subscribe(() => {
      expect(getReviewServiceSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
    }
}));
```